# Is there a better way to merge two obj in Javascript?(one key with multiple values)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, hashmap

there are two arrays of objects,

```
const students = [
  { student_id: 1, name: "Arthur" },
  { student_id: 2, name: "Peter" },
  { student_id: 3, name: "Molly" },
];
const student_objects = [
  { student_id: 1, object: "pen" },
  { student_id: 2, object: "pen" },
  { student_id: 3, object: "book" },
  { student_id: 1, object: "book" },
  { student_id: 3, object: "phone" },
];
```

the expected output :

```
[
  { student_id: 1, name: 'Arthur', object: [ 'pen', 'book' ] },
  { student_id: 2, name: 'Peter', object: [ 'pen' ] },
  { student_id: 3, name: 'Molly', object: [ 'book', 'phone' ] }
]
```

I tried two ways , the first one is :

```
function practice(students, student_objects) {
  students.forEach((ele) => (ele.object = []));
  for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < student_objects.length; j++) {
      if (student_objects[j].student_id === students[i].student_id) {
        students[i].object.push(student_objects[j].object);
      }
    }
  }
  return students;
}
```

and the second one is :

```
function practice(students, student_objects) {
  
  const student_objects_new = student_objects.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.student_id] = obj[item.student_id] || [];
    obj[item.student_id].push(item.object);
    return obj;
  }, {});
  
  const answer = students.map((element) => ({
    ...element,
    object: [...student_objects_new[element.student_id]],
  }));
  
  return answer;
}
```

both of the ways are not efficient , is there better ways to achieve the expected output?

Comment: The second one is efficient. It loops both arrays only once. And you can dirently assign: `object: student_objects_new[element.student_id]` No need for the additional spread.

Answer (score 1):

You could collect the objects first and then map the students with their objects.

Big O: O(n + m)

```js
const
    students = [{ student_id: 1, name: "Arthur" }, { student_id: 2, name: "Peter" }, { student_id: 3, name: "Molly" }],
    student_objects = [{ student_id: 1, object: "pen" }, { student_id: 2, object: "pen" }, { student_id: 3, object: "book" }, { student_id: 1, object: "book" }, { student_id: 3, object: "phone" }],
    relations = student_objects.reduce((r, { student_id, object }) => {
        (r[student_id] ??= []).push(object);
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = students.map(o => ({ ...o, objects: relations[o.student_id] || [] }));
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Their second code is same as this

Comment: @adiga, nearly. the last mapping takes into account unknown students.

Answer (score 0):

- You can try to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reorganize the *student_objects* array.

  ```
  {"1":["pen","book"],"2":["pen"],"3":["book","phone"]}
  ```

  > The above is the reorganized data format.

---

- Then when calling [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy the attributes, and add an array of objects based on *student_id* from the restructured data.

  > The reason for not reorganizing student_objects in the map.
  >
  > It is to avoid reorganizing the data every time and wasting resources.

**Below is an example of each step :**

```js
const students = [
  { student_id: 1, name: "Arthur" },
  { student_id: 2, name: "Peter" },
  { student_id: 3, name: "Molly" }
];

const student_objects = [
  { student_id: 1, object: "pen" },
  { student_id: 2, object: "pen" },
  { student_id: 3, object: "book" },
  { student_id: 1, object: "book" },
  { student_id: 3, object: "phone" }
];

const restructure = arr =>
  arr.reduce((accumu, {student_id, object}) => {
    accumu[student_id] = [...accumu[student_id] ?? '', object];
    return accumu;
  }, {});

const reorganized = restructure(student_objects);

const result = students.map(student => ({
  ...student,
  object: reorganized[student.student_id]
}));

result.forEach(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```

**Integrate steps and wrap into a function :**

```js
const students = [
  { student_id: 1, name: "Arthur" },
  { student_id: 2, name: "Peter" },
  { student_id: 3, name: "Molly" }
];

const student_objects = [
  { student_id: 1, object: "pen" },
  { student_id: 2, object: "pen" },
  { student_id: 3, object: "book" },
  { student_id: 1, object: "book" },
  { student_id: 3, object: "phone" }
];

const result = (students, student_objects) => {
  const reorganized = 
    student_objects.reduce((accumu, {student_id, object}) => {
      accumu[student_id] = [...accumu[student_id] ?? '', object];
      return accumu;
    }, {});
  return students.map(student => ({
    ...student,
    object: reorganized[student.student_id]
  }));
}

result(students, student_objects)
  .forEach(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```